# Test exception of a method which contains try catch in junit

Tags: junit4

I have code snippet below.

What I want is if getNames() method catch an exception 
( ex. InterruptedException ), 
want to check if `Got InterruptedException !!!` prints out or not.

There are some examples of testing exception for a method 
which throws an exception in its method ( ex. `String method1()  throws InterruptedException {...}` ) in the Internet.

But not this case. Does anyone have some thought or idea?

```
public class A {
    public List<String> getNames()
    {
        String addess = "address1";
        int age = 17;

        List<String> names = null;
        try {
            names = getSomeNames(address, sex);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new MyCustomException(e);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            throw new MyCustomException(e);
        }

        return names;
    }


    List<String> getSomeNames(String address, int sex) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
        // ...
        // throw exceptions... at some point
        //

        return names;                   
    }
}

public class MyCustomException extends Exception {
    public MyCustomException(Throwable e) {

        if (e.getCause() instanceof InterruptedException) {
            // write log
            System.out.println("Got InterruptedException !!!");
        }
        else if (e.getCause() instanceof ExecutionException) {
            // write log
            System.out.println("Got ExecutionException!!!");
        }
        else {
            // write log
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this but the test failed and got NullPointerException in catch block.

```
@Test  
public void testException() {
    A objA = spy(new A());

    try {
        doThrow(MyCustomException.class).when(objA).getNames();
        objA.getNnames();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getCause().toString());  // ==> throws java.lang.NullPointerException here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to test it.

First solution is to replace `System.out` with different stream and read from it later. ( I don't like this approach )

```
  @Test
    void whenSayHi_thenPrintlnCalled() throws IOException {
        PrintStream normalOutput = System.out;
        String result;
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); PrintStream temporalOutput = new PrintStream(baos)) {
            System.setOut(temporalOutput);
            ThatGuy thatGuy = new ThatGuy();
            thatGuy.sayHi();
            result = new String(baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } finally {
            System.setOut(normalOutput);
        }
        assertEquals("Hi", result.trim());
    }
```

Second one is to use `logger` instead of just `System.out`. I consider this approach better not only from testing, but from code design perspective as well. Using this one you can just replace `logger` with `Mockito.mock` and user `Mockito.verify` to check what was called on your `logger`.

```
  @Test
    void whenSayHi_thenCallLogger() {
        Logger logger = Mockito.mock(Logger.class);
        ThatGuy thatGuy = new ThatGuy();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(thatGuy, "logger", logger);
        thatGuy.sayHiToLog();
        verify(logger).error("Hi");
    }
```

Class under testing looks like this:

```
class ThatGuy {
        private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThatGuy.class);

        void sayHi() {
            System.out.println("Hi");
        }

        void sayHiToLog() {
            logger.error("Hi");
        }
 }
```